# Mysql and mongodb relationship in laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel

I tried to make  relationship to mysql with mongodb on laravel 5.3

First i created Content Model with mysql connection.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    /**
     *
     *      
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category', 'id', 'cid');
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag', 'cid', 'id');
    }
}
```

And then i created Tag Model with mongodb.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'tags';

    /**
     * Fillable fields
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['_id'];

    /**
     *
     *      
     */
    public function content()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Content', 'id', 'cid');
    }
}
```

Everything okey so far but when i try to get data, who get empty.

```
$contents = Content::with('category')->with('tags')->get();

        dd($contents[0]->tags);
```

Comment: You're trying to combine two database engines into one. I can't imagine how this would ever work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Moloquent documentation at https://moloquent.github.io/master/relations/#mysql-relations you will need to `use Moloquent\Eloquent\HybridRelations` trait in your sql model (App\Content).